# Bot framework v4: how to repeat waterfall step?

Tags: .net, botframework

Using a waterfall dialog, how can I repeat a step until the user input is as expected?

In detail:

Step 1: process user input and start a search using input

Step 2: the search result has placeholders and the values must be extracted from the original user input. If not all values can be identified, the bot must ask the user for more details and pick up execution in step 2.
If all values have been identified, move on to step 3.

Step 3: output search result and identified values.

Answer (score 0):

The sample library covers most use-cases.
Yours is covered by the complex dialog
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples